# batch file passing path with whitespaces

Tags: windows, batch-file

below is what I am trying to do, to run a cmd on a remote server.

One example in the serverList.txt:

servername&e:\a\b\c\abc edf\abc\

```
@echo on 
cd /d %~dp0 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
set serverList=serverList.txt 
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2* delims=&" %%A in ("%serverList%") DO ( 
    SET directory = %%B 
    wmic /node:%%A process call create "cmd /c cd /d !directory! & !directory!\hello.cmd" 
) 
endlocal 
Pause
```

but as you can see, the path of the directory has a white space in it, I tried double quotes but doesn't help. it doesn't do anything, without the space it works perfectly.

Wondering where I went wrong. Much appreciated!

JS

Comment: Is that the exact batch file you're using?  `!directory!` should be used instead of `%directory%` for `EnableDelayedExpansion` to work correctly.  I don't see how it would work with or without spaces in the directory name otherwise.

Comment: yeah tried !directory! but no luck. it was like "cmd /c cd /d %%B & %%B\hello.cmd" and worked perfectly untill I found some of the directory has space in between.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo on 
cd /d %~dp0 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
set "serverList=serverList.txt" 
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2* delims=&" %%A in ("%serverList%") DO ( 
    SET "directory=%%B"
    wmic /node:%%A process call create "cmd /c cd /d "!directory!" & "!directory!\hello.cmd"" 
) 
endlocal 
Pause
```

Comment: just tried and didn't work. thinking the quote should end in a different place?

Comment: I did a robocopy by robocopy "!directory!" and actually it did pick up the whole path with spaces. so wondering maybe something wrong with that wmic. :(

Answer (score 0):

You don't need delayed expansion as you can use %%B

If this fails the place an ECHO before the WMIC and see what it printed to the console.

```
@echo on 
cd /d %~dp0 
set "serverList=serverList.txt" 
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2* delims=&" %%A in ("%serverList%") DO ( 
    wmic /node:%%A process call create "cmd /c cd /d "%%B" & hello.cmd " 
) 
endlocal 
Pause
```

Or for kicks, try this.  Wmic is an odd tool with forIndo commands.

```
@echo on 
cd /d %~dp0 
set "serverList=serverList.txt" 
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2* delims=&" %%A in ("%serverList%") DO call :next "%%A" "%%B"
pause
goto :eof
:next
wmic /node:%~1 process call create "cmd /c cd /d "%~2" & hello.cmd " 
goto :EOF
```

Comment: tried both but no luck at my end. :(  thinking wmic has a different structure than I thought.